# Velocity.js run animations with duration in parallel

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, svg, velocity.js

In Velocity.js the default way animations (on an Object) are run is one after another in a queue.
You can run animations in parallel by using different named queues or the option `{queue: false}`.

This works fine like this:
https://codepen.io/JonasGruenwald/pen/pdpmVv

But once you add a duration option like `{duration: 300},` the animations will run one after another again: https://codepen.io/JonasGruenwald/pen/XzZMYw - both with named queues and the `{queue: false}` option.

Is there a way to run animations with (different) durations on the same object in parallel in Velocity.js?
Or is there some sort of workaround for this I can use? I'm trying to write a script to translate animations from a key frame based system to velocity so I'm looking for a way to animate different properties of an object independent from each other at the same time.

Comment: Isn't it: `mydiv
  .velocity({ translateX: 75 },{duration: 300, queue: "a" })
  .velocity({ translateY: 75 },{duration: 300, queue: "c" })`???

Comment: Why dont just `.velocity({ translateX: 75, translateY: 75 }, { duration: 300})`

Comment: @Vanojx1 Because I may have different durations for x and y translate in my usecase

Comment: @A.Wolff Thats solves it! Thank you so much!

Comment: Ok anyway the function takes an animation object and an options object, not 3 but 2 params

Comment: Yeah I suppose I had misunderstood it, thanks for your help as well!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered by A. Wolff in a comment, I had made an error passing two objects with options instead of one, it works correctly using `{duration: 300, queue: "a" }` instead of `{duration: 300}, { queue: "a" }`